# Regular Expression for a range >= 0 but less than 1000

Tags: regex

I am busy working on this and thought I would put it our there.

It must be a number with a maximum of 3 units and maximum of 5 decimal places etc

Valid

- 999.99999
- 99.9
- 9
- 0.99999
- 0

Invalid

- -0.1
- 999.123456
- AAA
- AAA.99999

**EDIT** It needs to be greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Do you actually mean less than 1000 (less than or equal to 999.99999) or do you mean less than 999.99999 (less than or equal to 999.99998)? Based on 999.99999 being valid, I assume you mean <1000.

Comment: Why on earth does this need to be done with a regular expression?

Comment: What about values like 001.01 , 9. , 0. ? Should these be valid numbers ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In light of your recent changes to the question, here is an updated regex which will match all >= 0 and <1000**

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,5})?$
  ^\___/ \/ ^\/\___/ |
  |  ^   ^  | |  |   `- Previous is optional (group of dot and minimum 1 number between 0-9 and optionally 4 extra numbers between 0-9)
  |  |   |  | |  `- Match 1-5 instances of previous (single number 0-9)
  |  |   |  | `- Match a single number 0-9
  |  |   |  `- The dot between the 1-3 first number(s) and the 1-5 last number(s).
  |  |   `- This round bracket should not create a backreference
  |  `- Match 1-3 instances of previous (single number 0-9)
  `- Match a single number 0-9
```

`^` is start of line, `$` is end of line.

*Valid*

- 999.99999
- 999.0
- 999
- 99.9
- 99.0
- 99
- 9
- 0.1
- 0.01
- 0.001
- 0.0001
- 0.99999
- 0.01234
- 0.00123
- 0.00012
- 0.00001
- 0.0
- 0.00000
- 0
- 000.00000
- 000

*Invalid*

- -0.1
- 999.123456
- AAA
- AAA.99999
- 0.
- .123

Comment: @Jonathan: Updated my answer to reflect your changes to the question.

Comment: @ohaal, no real need to keep old answer, there is edit history. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,5})?\b/  # the boundary \b prevents matching numbers after the max of 5
```

Edit: A quick search shows that as usual, there's a CPAN module for this.

[Regexp::Common::number](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anumber)

@ohaal correctly points out that this will also match 0, which is invalid. I suggest a combination of this regex and a test that the matched value is greater than 0.

Also see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=614452

Answer (score 1):

```
   ^([0-9].[0-9]{0,5}|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}.{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})$
```

Accepted
999.99999
99.9
9
0.99999

Rejected
-0.1
999.123456
AAA
AAA.99999
0

Comment: Your regex will match "0.0" and "0."

Comment: Sorry @ohaal I made a mistake 0 and 0.0 are valid values.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html
there's a lot of examples about numbers and discussions about pro- and cons
of different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Built off of answer by @ohaal above for currency $0.00 - $999.99

[Regex $0.00 - $999.99](https://regex101.com/r/GD98uw/2)

```
(\$(?!\d{1,3},\d{1,3})(?!\d{4})\d{1,3}(?!\d{1,3}\.\d\D)(?:\.\d{2,5})?)(?!\.)(?!,\d{3})
```